# The Groovy collection method addAll() works on single objects, but is it safe to use it this way?

Tags: groovy

While messing around I realized that I can do something like someList.addAll(someObject)... instead of using .add(someObject).  This does not seem to be documented and it would be nice to do this instead of checking an object instance's type before calling one or the other.  Is it safe to use it this way?

Comment: I'd think it was just varargs, but you'd have to be careful, because IIRC there's also an `addAll(index, collection)`.

Comment: I wondered as much.  That's pretty interesting.  It is probably not a good practice to do it...  but it would make the code so much neater.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Because it's exactly the:

```
def l = []
l.addAll('a')
l.addAll(['a'])

assert l == ['a', 'a']
```

In groovy parenthesis can be omitted and in both cases [this](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/gapi/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.html#addAll(Collection%3CT%3E,%20Iterable%3CT%3E)) method will be invoked.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in most cases this would be safe to use, but as Dave Newton pointed out there are times when, if the data being added is not under strict control, this could fail.  (ie. addAll(someInt)).  Because I cannot predict who will be using my code in the future, and how they might try to use it, I am going to stick with testing the incoming value and using add or addAll as appropriate.  While I love simplicity, sometimes I think it is better to be explicit and verbose.  :)

Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Although the [*varargs* section](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/#_varargs_tbd) of the official docs is empty, groovy follows a convention so that *if the last argument of a method is declared as Object[], it can be invoked with varargs*. I haven't found references to that convention apart from this [introduction to groovy](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/groovy-intro3/).

So I guess that when invoking `someList.addAll(someObject)` the varargs convention is followed and the [`Collection.addAll(Object\[\])`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#addAll(java.lang.Object[])) is eventually invoked.

So I would say that it is safe to use it that way.